# Vote early and often!

Tags: discussion, voting

I come from the MathOverflow 1.0 era, and back then we strongly emphasized voting; it made a lasting difference---[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) is still going strong.  If we want to build a community of active users, we need to learn to appreciate their contributions (especially useful, well-written, effortful answers), otherwise users might not bother using the site or putting effort into their posts.

Perhaps it's time to re-post [Scott Morrison](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often)'s post as to why voting is so essential:

> I'm a moderator from MathOverflow, and this "question" is actually
> unsolicited advice, based on our experience from the initial launch of
> MathOverflow.
>
> > We should encourage everyone to vote positively as often as possible!
>
> Every Stack Exchange site will eventually end up with a different
> "base level" of voting --- that is, the expected number of upvotes for
> a question of a given level of excellence. (This effect occurs because
> people see a good question, but already with a certain number of
> votes, and think "oh, I would have upvoted this, but it already has
> enough".)
>
> It's easy for us to affect this "base level" by encouraging high
> levels of upvoting now. We're setting the standards, and this really
> will have an effect.
>
> (On MathOverflow, we were very active about this early on,
> specifically encouraging all the initial round of users to vote early
> and often. You can compare statistics, and see that the average vote
> total for a MathOverflow question is much higher than on any of the
> other SE 1.0 sites.)
>
> In case it's not obvious: the rationale for wanting this base level to
> be high is that it provides better positive feedback to good
> contributors.

Comment: I would like to ask for a reference for _You can compare statistics, and see that the average vote total for a MathOverflow question is much higher than on any of the other SE 1.0 sites._.

Comment: I think this question's title should be changed as it doesn't match the quoted content, as such content promotes upvoting with different purposes than the feature intention. I think that the title of the quoted content should also be changed. Remember, the titles of the public Q&A platform are intended to be a summary of what is being asked, they should not be written following the practices seen on other places like blogs.